# If the Dwarves had a battle in their own kingdom, then why was Gimli part of the journey with Frodo and the Ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, dwarves

I asked a question yesterday about why the Lonely Mountain and the Dwarves weren't featured in The Lord of the Rings, and I got answers explaining how they were in their own battle. But if that was so, then surely Gimli son of Glóin wouldn't have been in attendance at the Council of Elrond in Rivendell?

Comment: Well, Gondor and Mirkwood had battles with the forces of Sauron, but Boromir and Legolas went to the Council. Why should Gimli be different?

Answer (score 15):

Because the battle had not started yet, they looking for advice on what to do about the emissary from Sauron, and hoping for news about the attempt to recolonize Moria.

Comment: But it says that when frodo is at the seat of seeing that he looks to the north and see's the dwarfs in battle with the bear people

Comment: Frodo sitting in the seat of seeing doesn't happen until several weeks (if not months) after the Council of Elrond - and Gimli and Gloin would have had to leave the Lonely Mountain some weeks before they left to visit Rivendell. Plenty of time for Sauron to attack the dwarves and prevent their coming to aid the South.

Comment: @charlie73 - Also Frodo is seeing the future at the Seat of Seeing; read my answer at http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79127/who-attacked-the-land-of-the-beornings-during-the-war-of-the-ring/79129#79129 for evidence of that.

Comment: plus if your gimli, your now weeks or months away from home, how are you supposed to get back home. And i dont think frodo tells anyone about his visions? since he runs off with sam right afterwards.

Answer (score 9):

Why couldn't a single dwarf be elsewhere, even if other dwarves are fighting battles?

The dwarves of Erebor are worried, because nobody has heard anything from Moria for a long time after Balin went to reclaim it, and because of a messenger from Sauron who has come to them asking about rings and hobbits, and making veiled threats. So they send Glóin (the same one from The Hobbit) to Rivendel to warn Bilbo and get advice from Elrond. This is Glóin speaking, at the Council of Elrond:

> 'Then about a year ago a messenger came to Dáin, but not from Moria—from Mordor: a horseman in the night, who called Dáin to his gate. The Lord Sauron the Great, so he said, wished for our friendship. Rings he would give for it, such as he gave of old. And he asked urgently concerning *hobbits*, of what kind they were, and where they dwelt. "For Sauron knows," said he, "that one of these was known to you at a time."

(...)

> 'And so I have been sent at last by Dáin to warn Bilbo that he is sought by the Enemy, and to learn, if may be, why he desires this ring, this least of rings. Also we crave the advice of Elrond. For the Shadow grows and draws nearer. We discover that messengers have come also to King Brand in Dale and that he is afraid.

Gimli is in Rivendel accompanying Glóin, his father. When the Fellowship of the Ring is formed, Elrond volunteers Gimli to go with them to help Frodo and represent the dwarves.